# Django+Docker+SSL: How to force CSRF to work with HTTPS on Nginx+Gunicorn+Docker stack?

Tags: django, ssl, https, csrf-protection, django-csrf

Problem started when after accessing my host via `https` I encountered that DRF serializes my image it shows url with `http://` prefix. Then I've modified next files:
**nginx.conf**

```
server {
    server_name core.antu.ge;
    charset UTF-8;
    ssl on;
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/server.key;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/core.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/core.error.log;

    location /static/ {
    autoindex on;
        root /;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:8000;
        proxy_pass_header X-CSRFToken;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol https;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

**settings.py**

```
if not DEBUG:
    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

As a result, I have https prefix in drf as I want but when I perform any POST request I get that error:
[image]

P.S I'm not going to disable csrf middleware or write `csrf_exempt`!

**UPD**
With `DEBUG = True` all works fine :/

Comment: the error message clearly says " MOre information available with Debug=true" you need to check that and if you can't still figure it out then add it to the question

Comment: with debug=True all works fine (see settings.py code). I definitively need SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER field to be filled

Comment: which sounds extremely strange because the debug flag does nto effect CSRF behaviour

Comment: You can see that I set up CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE to be True when DEBUG is unset, but I've added this line for resolving this issue. I have no idea :(